# RecyclerView avoid to reload items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a recycler view in which there are some items containing complex custom component to load. It takes times to load and the problem is the recycler view call whenever necessary the method "onBindViewHolder" (during scroll etc) to recreate the views and so it needs time again to regenerate all the item (I'm not talking about the item's XML layout). And so... not very cool for performance.

How to avoid recreating a item ?

I tried to call :

```
setIsRecyclable
```

But it doesn't work.

Example :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
    // CODE 1 : treatments applied to the item view
    // the problem is here, I don't want to repeat this code when it's already done
}
```

Comment: have you generate your ViewHolder or not  in your adapter?

Comment: Ye yep, I've a view holder etc....

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: The problem is about the method "onBindViewHolder". how to avoid performing treatments already done for an item?

Answer (score 4):

Why not have a hashmap where you store a boolean value to indicate if you have performed operation at the position?

```
HashMap<Integer,boolean> operations = new HashMap<>();

 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
      if(operations.contains(position){
         //Do nothing..
      }
      else
      {
        //Do operations...
        operations.put(position,true);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Yep I thought about a simply solution but.... Didn't Android  have any plans for such a simple case?!

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Handler timerHandler;
    timerHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { // Here you can update your adapter data

            mRecyclerView.invalidate();


             My_function();

            // mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);

            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            //Toast.makeText(Chat_Activity.this, "Refreace", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 3000);
```

Comment: Yep I can do the work to do in another thread; but the problem still the same. How to avoid in onBindViewHolder to do a work already did ?

Answer (score 0):

in your  `onBindViewHolder`
generate `Asynctask` and in `doInBackground` do your content setting process.